# Calendar Year View -

Tags: c#, asp.net, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am looking for a control (UWP or ASP.NET) that gives me a calendar year view (Fiscal year ;-) ) and lets me categorize the days. So I would like to be able to click a day and then choose a color that indicates busy, available, ... Or how could I create something myself that enables this functionality?

Currently I use this to plan days ahead.
It looks like this in excel.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the `Background` of the `CalendarViewDayItem`, we should be able to use the `CalendarViewDayItemChangingEventArgs.Item` property to get `CalendarViewDayItem`in the `CalendarViewDayItemChanging` event.

An we should be able to create a class that it has MyColor and MyDateTime property to save the `Color` and `DateTime`.

For example:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <CalendarView Name="MyCalendarView" SelectedDatesChanged="MyCalendarView_SelectedDatesChanged" CalendarViewDayItemChanging="MyCalendarView_CalendarViewDayItemChanging"></CalendarView>
</Grid>
```

The code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        times = new ObservableCollection<DayItem>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            times.Add(new DayItem(new DateTime(2017, 1, i), Colors.Yellow));
        }

        for (int i = 10; i < 20; i++)
        {
            times.Add(new DayItem(new DateTime(2016, 12, i), Colors.Green));
        }
        for (int i = 20; i < 29; i++)
        {
            times.Add(new DayItem(new DateTime(2017, 1, i), Colors.Red));
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<DayItem> times;

    private void MyCalendarView_SelectedDatesChanged(CalendarView sender, CalendarViewSelectedDatesChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        bool add = false;
        //If we double click the CalendarViewDayItem, the second time args.AddedDates.Count is 0
        if (args.AddedDates.Count >= 1) 
        {
            var newDate = args.AddedDates[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < times.Count; i++)
            {
                if (newDate.Date.Year == times[i].MyDateTime.Year && newDate.Date.Month == times[i].MyDateTime.Month && newDate.Date.Day == times[i].MyDateTime.Day)
                {
                    add = true;
                }
            }
            if (!add)
            {
                times.Add(new DayItem(newDate.DateTime, Colors.Green));
            }
        }
    }

    private void MyCalendarView_CalendarViewDayItemChanging(CalendarView sender, CalendarViewDayItemChangingEventArgs args)
    {
        var selectDay = args.Item as CalendarViewDayItem;
        for (int i = 0; i < times.Count; i++)
        {
            if (selectDay.Date.Year == times[i].MyDateTime.Year && selectDay.Date.Month == times[i].MyDateTime.Month && selectDay.Date.Day == times[i].MyDateTime.Day)

                selectDay.Background = new SolidColorBrush(times[i].MyColor);
        }
    }
}

internal class DayItem
{
    public DayItem(DateTime today, Color red)
    {
        MyDateTime = today;
        MyColor = red;
    }

    public Color MyColor { get; set; }
    public DateTime MyDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

When we set the `Background` of the `CalendarViewDayItem`, the `CalendarViewDayItemChanging` will not be fired. It occurs when a CalendarViewDayItem is loading. So you should be able to reload the CalendarViewDayItem.

Also if you want to show the Calendar Year View, you should be able to use 12 CalendarViews on the page.

Comment: Thanks for the insights!
I'll go ahead and create a custom yearview control, which indeed uses 12 CalendarView controls. That way it's possible to add custom properties like start and end of the fiscal year to the custom control. Nice!